# Tailwind css with Angular not working properly

Tags: angular, web, responsive-design, tailwind-css

I was using **tailwind css** on an **angular project**, One issue that I noted while using tailwind on angular is that, most of the properties are not working properly like- **dropdowns, fonts, carousels**,

Cant figure out why..

**style.css**

```
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';
```

**tailwind.config.js**

````
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{html,ts}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}```




If any one have any solutions or any alternative methods,** please do suggest**
````